# Writing programmatically lines of text in a Word cell

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I am developping a .Net console application which creates a Word document.
My Visual Studio project has a reference to the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word assembly.

I want to create a table cell.
I want to write two lines of text in the cell.
The first line must be bold.

Here is my code :

```
l_table = l_range.Tables.Add(l_range, 1, 1);
l_table.Borders.Enable = 0;
l_table.Rows.AllowBreakAcrossPages = 0;

l_cellRange = l_table.Cell(1, 1).Range;
l_cellRange.Text = "First Line";
l_cellRange.Bold = 1;

l_cellRange.InsertParagraphAfter();
l_cellRange.Collapse(WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);
l_cellRange.Text = "Second Line";
l_cellRange.Bold = 1;
```

The following code line raises an exception : l_cellRange.Text = "Second Line";
The exception message (Translation from French to English) : Unvalid action at end of line

Can someone explain me what is wrong with my code ?

Comment: If you are just starting with generation of Word documents - I advise that you go down different path - create word docs from XMLs instead of directly controlling Word process. Do Google Search for more info, but you can start with this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15004/Create-simple-Word-2007-documents-without-needing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a call to `Range.MoveEnd()`.

Per the [MSDN documentation on Range.InsertParagraphAfter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.range.insertparagraphafter%28v=office.14%29.aspx), the Range expands to include the new paragraph when you insert a paragraph.

Then, when you collapse the range, which already includes the new paragraph, you are moving the range's start and end positions to **after** the ending paragraph mark. [MSDN's article on Range.Collapse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.range.collapse%28v=office.14%29.aspx) specifically mentions this effect and how to fix it.

In short, you need to insert `MoveEnd()` after your call to `Collapse()`:

```
l_cellRange.Collapse(WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);
l_cellRange.MoveEnd(WdUnits.wdCharacter, -1);
l_cellRange.Text = "Second Line";
```

This will move the range start and end positions to just before the end paragraph mark and allow you to insert text as expected.

Having said all that, I agree with kape123. Generating the document via XML is the more sustainable way to go.